# Function works correctly only the first time it is called

Tags: python, function, file, python-3.x

I have the following function, the second function `count_forbid(a)` can only work 1 time. In this example it count the right value of the word that do not contain letter `'c'`, but for `y` it return zero. So it means the code can only do right first time and for all other time it return zero:

```
import string
fin = open('words.txt')
def forbid_or_not(word,forb):
    for letter in word:
        if letter in forb:
            return False
    return True

def count_forbid(a):
    count = 0
    for line in fin:
        word1 = line.strip()
        if forbid_or_not(word1,a):
            count += 1
    return count

x = count_forbid('c')
y = count_forbid('d')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you iterate through the file with:

```
    for line in fin:
```

*it is going to reach the end* and trying to re-iterate will have no effect.

Either change the function to use a [**context manager**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase) that re-opens the file when the function is called:

```
def count_forbid(a):
    count = 0
    with open('words.txt') as fin:  # closes the file automatically
        for line in fin:
            word1 = line.strip()
            if forbid_or_not(word1,a):
                count += 1
    return count
```

which is the preferred way of opening files in python.

Or, add [`fin.seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.seek) in between your calls in order to get the file to point to the beginning:

```
x = count_forbid('c')
fin.seek(0)
y = count_forbid('d')
```

Comment: Instead of using the context manager you can also just "manually" open and close the file.

Comment: Of course, but that relies on the fact that you're vigilant and always remember to close it. That's why context managers are such a nice construct, they do that for you and let you worry about more important things :-).

Comment: WOW, super effective, thank a lot.

Comment: @AnhHoang if this solved your issue you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the tick mark next to the answer :-)

Comment: @Jim True, and one should use the context managers, but the wording implied to me that using a context manager or using seek are the only options available. I think it's important to understand that a context manager is only "syntactic sugar" and does not anything that couldn't be achieved otherwise.

Comment: @Jim I marked it, thanks, I am just a newbie first time use stackoverflow so very sorry for the delay tick.